# Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Stored Procedure, that is executed on a VB.Net system.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE EsRl230

    @EMPCod         NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SGPId              NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @MAPId          NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @DtNaoVendido           NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @DtCadastro         NVARCHAR(MAX)

    AS
    DECLARE @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql =          
    'SELECT ' +
        'EMPSigla, ' +
        'GRPCod, ' +
        'GRPDesc, ' +
        'SGPCod, ' +
        'SGPDesc, ' +
        'MAPDesc, ' +
        'PROCod, ' +
        'PROCodFab, ' +
        'PRODesc = SUBSTRING(PRODesc,1,50), ' +
        'PROAplic = SUBSTRING(PROAplic,1,100), ' +
        'PREQtEst,   ' +
        'PREPrVd, ' +
        'PRECstRp, ' +
        'COSDtFec, ' +
        'CNEDtLib ' +
    'FROM ' +
        'EsPRE (NoLock) ' +
      'JOIN GnEMP (NoLock) ON EsPRE.EMPCod = GnEMP.EMPCod ' +  
        'JOIN EsINE (NoLock) ON EsPRE.PREid = EsINE.PREid ' +
        'JOIN EsCNE (NoLock) ON EsINE.CNEId = EsCNE.CNEId ' +
      'JOIN EsPRO (NoLock) ON EsPRE.PROId = EsPRO.PROId ' +  
        'JOIN EsSGP (NoLock) ON EsPRO.SGPId = EsSGP.SGPId  ' +
        'JOIN EsGRP (NoLock) ON EsSGP.GRPId = EsGRP.GRPId ' +
        'LEFT JOIN EsMAP (NoLock) ON EsPRO.MAPId = EsMAP.MAPId ' +
        'JOIN SeCOS (NoLock) ON  SeCOS.EMPCod = GnEMP.EMPCod ' +
        'JOIN SeCRQ (NoLock) ON SeCOS.COSid = SeCRQ.COSid ' +
    'WHERE ' +
        'EsPRE.EMPCod IN (' + @EMPCod + ') ' 

    IF @SGPId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + 'AND SGPId IN ' + @SGPId 
    END

    IF @MAPId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET  @sql = @sql +  'AND MAPId IN (' + @MAPId + ') ' 
    END

    IF @DtNaoVendido IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + 'AND COSDtFec >= ' + @DtNaoVendido
    END

    IF @DtCadastro IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CNEDtLib <= '  + @DtCadastro 
    END

    EXEC (@sql)

    GO
```

And its being executed this way :

```
execute EsRl230 '297', NULL, NULL, '02/04/2018' ,'23/04/2018'
```

And it returns me the following error:

> "Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int"

Can someone help me?

Comment: Pull your code out of the procedure, run it normally, and see where the error occurs.

Comment: If you use TVPs and proper parameters instead of a comma-separated list for `@EmpCode` and string concatenation, you can defeat three things at once: dynamic SQL, SQL injection, and data type mismatches.

Comment: Your best friend: `PRINT @SQL`. Also, `'EsPRE.EMPCod IN (' + @EMPCod + ') ' `, and `SET @sql = @sql + 'AND SGPId IN ' + @SGPId `, and more? I assume you're a fan of SQL Injection? :) Your query is wide open to it.

Comment: And all those NOLOCK hints....are you 100% sure you know all the fun and sinister aspects of that hint. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ If you are dead set on continuing it usage you need to include the WITH keyword. Omitting is has been deprecated.

Comment: I think these are the problem: AND COSDtFec >= ' + *DtNaoVendido' AND CNEDtLib <= '  + *DtCadastro you are comparing a date with a string - try making your last two input parameters datetimes

Comment: Also, stop declaring everything as an `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. If you are comparing dates, define the variable as a date(time) datatype. Always use the appropriate datatype, it's what they are there for!

Answer (score 0):

Other than lots of errors mentioned in comments, here is WHERE clause of this query. Check how dates are being used.

It would be better to PRINT dynamic SQL and run it separately before executing it directly through stored procedure.

```
WHERE EsPRE.EMPCod IN (297)  AND COSDtFec >= 02 / 04 / 2018  AND CNEDtLib <= 23 / 04 / 2018
```

You may try following:

```
create or alter PROCEDURE EsRl230
@EMPCod         NVARCHAR(MAX),
@SGPId              NVARCHAR(MAX),
@MAPId          NVARCHAR(MAX),
@DtNaoVendido           NVARCHAR(MAX),
@DtCadastro         NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS
DECLARE @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql =          
'SELECT ' +
    'EMPSigla, ' +
    'GRPCod, ' +
    'GRPDesc, ' +
    'SGPCod, ' +
    'SGPDesc, ' +
    'MAPDesc, ' +
    'PROCod, ' +
    'PROCodFab, ' +
    'PRODesc = SUBSTRING(PRODesc,1,50), ' +
    'PROAplic = SUBSTRING(PROAplic,1,100), ' +
    'PREQtEst,   ' +
    'PREPrVd, ' +
    'PRECstRp, ' +
    'COSDtFec, ' +
    'CNEDtLib ' +
'FROM ' +
    'EsPRE (NoLock) ' +
  'JOIN GnEMP (NoLock) ON EsPRE.EMPCod = GnEMP.EMPCod ' +  
    'JOIN EsINE (NoLock) ON EsPRE.PREid = EsINE.PREid ' +
    'JOIN EsCNE (NoLock) ON EsINE.CNEId = EsCNE.CNEId ' +
  'JOIN EsPRO (NoLock) ON EsPRE.PROId = EsPRO.PROId ' +  
    'JOIN EsSGP (NoLock) ON EsPRO.SGPId = EsSGP.SGPId  ' +
    'JOIN EsGRP (NoLock) ON EsSGP.GRPId = EsGRP.GRPId ' +
    'LEFT JOIN EsMAP (NoLock) ON EsPRO.MAPId = EsMAP.MAPId ' +
    'JOIN SeCOS (NoLock) ON  SeCOS.EMPCod = GnEMP.EMPCod ' +
    'JOIN SeCRQ (NoLock) ON SeCOS.COSid = SeCRQ.COSid ' +
'WHERE ' +
    'EsPRE.EMPCod IN (' + @EMPCod + ') ' 

IF @SGPId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND SGPId IN ' + @SGPId 
END

IF @MAPId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET  @sql = @sql +  'AND MAPId IN (' + @MAPId + ') ' 
END

IF @DtNaoVendido IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND COSDtFec >= ''' + @DtNaoVendido + ''''
END

IF @DtCadastro IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CNEDtLib <= '''  + @DtCadastro  + ''''
END

--EXEC (@sql)
PRINT @sql

GO
```

Comment: SQL Injection is still a huge problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't not fix this. People leaving their queries/SP open to SQL Injection  is a **huge** pet peeve of mine. In 2018 it should not be something people are leaving themselves open to. It terrifies me that people are still using poor practices like string concatenation to create dynamic SQL or inline statements in their application.

I've had to guess in some places, and assume your SQL Server version; there are comments in the code as to why or what I've guessed/assumed. I've also removed those *filthy* `NOLOCK` hints, as you've not given a good reason as to why you're using it (thus I can only assume you're using it for the wrong reasons, as so many seem to do). I **strongly** suggest you review this and understand why I have done this the way I have. I also suggest you read up on SQL Injection. It's clear you don't understand what it is, as you never would have written a query such as you have if you did understand all the implications being it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EsRl230 @EMPCod NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        @SGPId NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        @MAPId NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        @DtNaoVendido date, --Guessed data type
                        @DtCadastro date --Guessed data type

AS
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @params nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @sql =          
    N'SELECT EMPSigla,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       GRPCod,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       GRPDesc,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       SGPCod,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       SGPDesc,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       MAPDesc,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       PROCod,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       PROCodFab,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       PRODesc = SUBSTRING(PRODesc,1,50), ' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       PROAplic = SUBSTRING(PROAplic,1,100), ' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       PREQtEst,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       PREPrVd,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       PRECstRp,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       COSDtFec,' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'       CNEDtLib' + NCHAR(10) +
    N'FROM EsPRE ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why is it there?
    N'     JOIN GnEMP ON EsPRE.EMPCod = GnEMP.EMPCod ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     JOIN EsINE ON EsPRE.PREid = EsINE.PREid ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     JOIN EsCNE ON EsINE.CNEId = EsCNE.CNEId ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     JOIN EsPRO ON EsPRE.PROId = EsPRO.PROId ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     JOIN EsSGP ON EsPRO.SGPId = EsSGP.SGPId  ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     JOIN EsGRP ON EsSGP.GRPId = EsGRP.GRPId ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     LEFT JOIN EsMAP ON EsPRO.MAPId = EsMAP.MAPId ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     JOIN SeCOS ON  SeCOS.EMPCod = GnEMP.EMPCod ' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'     JOIN SeCRQ ON SeCOS.COSid = SeCRQ.COSid' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'WHERE EsPRE.EMPCod IN (SELECT SS.[value]' + NCHAR(10) + --Removed Nolock. Why was it there?
    N'                       FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dEmpCod,'','') SS)'; --Guessed you're using SQL Server 2016+

    IF @SGPId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND SGPId IN @dSGPId';
    END

    IF @MAPId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET  @sql = @sql + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND MAPId IN (SELECT SS.[value]' + NCHAR(10) +
                                       N'                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dMAPId,'','') SS)'; --Guessed you're using SQL Server 2016+
    END

    IF @DtNaoVendido IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND COSDtFec >= @dDtNaoVendido';
    END

    IF @DtCadastro IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + NCHAR(10) + N'  AND CNEDtLib <= @dDtCadastro';
    END

    SET @sql = @sql + N';';

    PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
    SET @params = N'@dEmpCod nvarchar(MAX), @dSGPId nvarchar(MAX), @dMAPId nvarchar(MAX), @dDtNaoVendido date, @dDtCadastro date'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @dEmpCod = @EMPCod, @dSGPId = @SGPId, @dMAPId = @MAPId, @dDtNaoVendido = @DtNaoVendido, @dDtCadastro = @DtCadastro;
GO
```

Also, please note this SQL in **untested**. Use your best friend to debug it, it if isn't working.

Comment: The NoLocks are used because this DB is on Azure, anda it is used by more than 300 diferent clientes, so if someone is using a table, and if i not use NoLocks, that user will need to wait until de table stop to be used

Comment: And there is no problem about SQL Injection on this casa, because it is only to be used on a report...products report..

Comment: Saying there is "no chance" doesn't mean there isn't, nor does it mean you should write bad code.

Comment: As for `NOLOCK`, are you saying your users are happy with inaccurate data? If the reason you're using it is because the query is slow, and therefore you want to avoid the locks (which it actually doesn't), then you should be looking to improve the query speed, not just filling your query with `NOLOCK`.